# Mocking GMSPlace

Tags: ios, swift, unit-testing, mocking, google-places

I'm currently using Google Places, and created an abstracted place picker, also a concrete implementation using Google Places.

I'm doing some unit tests for it. I came to the step where I want to mock GMSPlace (https://developers.google.com/places/ios-sdk/reference/interface_g_m_s_place)

The problem is that GMSPlace class have default initialization unavailable.

```
/**
 * Default init is not available.
 */
- (instancetype)init NS_UNAVAILABLE;
```

Can somebody share how can we mock things on these cases where init is not available?

Thanks

Comment: I am also finding a way to mock GMSPlace in swift. I am unable to write unit test case. Any luck if some solution provided.

Comment: I am trying to write XCTest case for below code. Please help

func lookupAddress(placeId: String) {
        let placesClient = GMSPlacesClient()
        placesClient.lookUpPlaceID(placeId, callback: { [weak self] (place, _) in
            guard let strongSelf = self else { return }
            if let place = place {
                // Handle case if valid place return
                self?.callMethodToGetAddressComponentsFromReturnValue(place)
            } else {
                // Handle case if nil value returns
            }
        })
    }

Comment: Hello there, have you found any solution about mocking GMSPlace?

Comment: @LucianoPerez posted an answer, maybe it can help

Comment: @EgzonArifi thanks but it does not work. I need to mock a GMSPlace somehow. I was able to override lookUpPlaceID but I am not able to create/Mock the completion with a place for this method.

`code`override func lookUpPlaceID(_ placeID: String, callback: @escaping (GMSPlace?, Error?) -> Void)

Answer (score 0):

This could be an alternative to test GMSPlace. So, GMSPlace is a class in the Google Places API for iOS. It represents a particular place, including its name, address, and other details. If you want to mock GMSPlace for testing purposes, you can use dependency injection and protocols.

1 - Create a protocol that represents the necessary properties and methods you need from GMSPlace.

```
 protocol Place {
    var name: String { get }
    var placeID: String { get }
    // Add other properties and methods you need
 }
```

2 - Create a mock class that conforms to the Place protocol.

```
class MockPlace: Place {
    var name: String
    var placeID: String
    // Add other properties and methods you need
        
    init(name: String, placeID: String) {
      self.name = name
      self.placeID = placeID
    }
}
```

3- Extend the GMSPlace class to conform to your Place protocol.

```
extension GMSPlace: Place {
    // GMSPlace already provides the required properties and methods,
    // so you don't need to add anything here.
}
```

4- Modify your code to depend on the Place protocol rather than the GMSPlace class directly. This allows you to use either a real GMSPlace object or a MockPlace object in your code, making it more testable.

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController {
 var selectedPlace: Place?

 func didSelectPlace(place: Place) {
    selectedPlace = place
    // Do something with the selected place
 }
}
```

5- Now you can use your MockPlace class for testing purposes.

```
func testDidSelectPlace() {
 let myViewController = MyViewController()
 let mockPlace = MockPlace(name: "Test Place", placeID: "123456")

 myViewController.didSelectPlace(place: mockPlace)

 XCTAssertEqual(myViewController.selectedPlace?.name, "Test Place")
 XCTAssertEqual(myViewController.selectedPlace?.placeID, "123456")
}
```